# How to display Recipient Address, Change Address & Transaction Amount

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, address

I have made A software in which i can Signed Transaction (From Electrum Un-Signed Transaction HEX), i just want to display the following thing to USER in Readable Mode :
1. Recipient Address
2. Change Address
3. Transaction Amount

How can i show this to USER to readable form so that user verify the Transaction before going broadcast.

Thanks, 
Amish Sharma

Comment: This is not possible. Just a raw transaction does not contain this information.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to BTC explorer any search in google 
example:
https://www.blockchain.com/explorer
type your wallet adress or transaction ID
And check.

Comment: I am developing a Desktop App, so need to calculate by my own / by hand /by code....

Comment: Do we have any procedure to get all of these value ?